# Tag [webtest] is being misused but is poorly named

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The description of the tag [webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtest) relates to a testing facility in Python and WSGI. There appear to be many questions using this tag that have nothing to do with Python, there are eleven (11) pages of questions with this tag. Perhaps many of these questions should have been tagged [web-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-testing).

The term "webtest" seems generic and hence a good candidate for any question about testing web based systems.

Perhaps the [webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtest) should be renamed to [python-webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-webtest) or [wsgi-webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsgi-webtest) or similar and all the non-Python-non-WSGI questions be retagged with something else.

Perhaps the [webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtest) and [web-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-testing) tags should be made synonymous, with an appropriate rewording of their descriptions.

What, if anything, should be done about these two tags and the many questions that have the wrong tag?